# Live SASS in Chrome DevTools troubleshooting (mapping lost for one file only)

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment

I've set up my SASS environment with source map, and everything works fine – the mapping works like it should and all CSS rules points to the correct scss-files in DevTools. But when enabling Live SASS, suddenly the mapping for my _main.scss is broken. The mapping works for all other scss-files except this one. In inspector it just points to the generated style.css.

I've tried removing the workspace and setting it up again, and I've tried resetting the DevTools settings. I've also tried renaming my _main.scss to something else.

I have a hard time with this one, so if anyone have suggestions to how I can troubleshoot this further it'd be much appreciated.

---

If activating Persistence 2.0 you can see which files are mapped:

[image: Mapped files]

In inspector, before activating Live SASS:

[image: Inspector, before activating Live SASS]

In inspector, after activating Live SASS:

[image: Inspector, after activating Live SASS]